# Using Array.map with new Array constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I was trying to use `new Array()` constructor with `map` in order to create a one-line code that creates a list of elements. Something like this :

```js
let arr = new Array(12).map( (el, i) => {
  console.log('This is never called');
  return i + 1;
});
```

Reading [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the behaviour makes sense.

> Basically docs say that callback of map will be executed even for declared undefined values in array, but not for example when creating empty Arrays like the code before.

So this should work :

```js
var arr = new Array(12);

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){
  arr[i] = undefined;
}

let list = arr.map( (e, i) => {
  console.log(i + 1);
  return i + 1;
});
```

So, We also can do something like this :

```js
let newArray = (length) => {
  let myArray = new Array(length);
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) myArray[i] = undefined;
  return myArray;
};

console.log( newArray(12).map( (el, i) => i + 1 ) );
```

**So my question. Is there a better/pretty way to do it with map function ?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array having passed length.

```
Array.from({length: 12}, (e, i) => i + 1);
```

Comment: Pretty cool! I'll give a read to Array.from docs! Thanks for this useful answer! Answer will be marked in 9 minutes! =)

Comment: I'm not the voter, but I would point out that `Array.from` accepts a callback that behaves like `.map()`. If you use that, then you're not creating an unnecessary intermediate Array.

Comment: I don't know. I upvoted you. I think is pretty cool, so i'm gonna mark this answer because is cleaner and works for me. And was the first. =)

Comment: @squint You're right, but that's my fault because of lack of knowledge, because I say that I want to use map, so  Array.from({length: 12}, (el, i) => i +1); should work as intended in the question.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: Yes, you did ask for `.map`. I'm just pointing it out so that people don't unnecessarily use this in practice. Nothing wrong with this answer from what I can see, so +1.

Comment: @squint and Tushar. I appreciate your help! =)

Answer (score 11):

If I am not mistaken, you explicitly said that you wanted an answer with **new Array** constructor.

Here is how to do it. One line, beautiful ES6:

```
let me = [...new Array(5)].map((x,i)=>i)
// [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Explanation:

1. `new Array(5)` generates this: `[ , , , ,  ]​​​​​`
2. `[...new Array(5)]` is a shorthand for `Array.from(new Array(5))`,
   and generates this: `​​​​​[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]​​​​​`, that is an array of `undefined`
   objects. Yes, `undefined` is a value (a primitive one :) ).
3. Now we can iterate over the values of our brand new array :D

PS: you can even skip the `new` keyword and do:

```
[...Array(5)].map((x,i)=>i)
```

Extra: Tersest expression

```
[...Array(5).keys()] // [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 6):

[Section 22.1.3.15](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map) of [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) is getting you, with the last line of `NOTE 1`:

> *callbackfn* is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

This behavior is shared by `filter`, `forEach`, and the other functional methods.

The array constructor you are calling, `Array(len)` from [section 22.1.1.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len), will set the length of the array but not initialize the elements. I'm not sure where the spec defines what a missing element is, but the array produced by `new Array(len)` should fit that and so none of the elements will be touched by `map`.

Comment: The array created by `new Array(n)` contains **holes** i.e. `[undefined × n]` and thus cannot be iterate over by `map`, `filter`, `forEach`...

Comment: @Tushar the spec considers the array to have missing elements, not "holes." There are subtle differences between a sparse array and one with unset elements like this.

Comment: It doesn't initialize the array with `undefined` values. Simply put the object doesn't have any properties from 0 to whatever length was specified.

Answer (score 3):

I like this approach because it still works in ES5:

```
let arr = Array.apply(null, Array(12))
    .map(function (x, i) {
        return i
    });

// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Since `New Array` returns an array that contains "holes", we use apply because apply treats holes as if they were undefined. This spreads undefined across the entire array which makes it mappable.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but could you please explain me why it works? What is Array.apply() doing?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, I've added some clarification to my answer.  Also, here is some documentation on [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with an object with the length in it.

```js
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 12 }).map((_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answer of @ssube

```js
let arr = new Array(12).fill(0).map( (el, i) => {
  console.log(`This should called ${i} times`);
  return i + 1;
});
// output;
// This should called 0 times
// This should called 1 times
// This should called 2 times
// This should called 3 times
// This should called 4 times
// This should called 5 times
// This should called 6 times
// This should called 7 times
// This should called 8 times
// This should called 9 times
// This should called 10 times
// This should called 11 times
```