# Understanding javascript Array() function

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I write this code: `Array(3).map( () => ({ a:1 }) )` I get `Array(3) [ <3 empty slots> ]` instead of an array of 3 objects. Why is that?

As far as I know, `Array(3)` will produce an array of `undefined` elements with length 3. And for instance, `[1, 2, 3].map( () => ({ a:1 }) )` produces the expected output. This is true also using any other array with length 3. I'm intrigued.

Comment: Perhaps this page might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487602/using-array-map-with-new-array-constructor

Answer (score 1):

`Array(3)` creates an empty array of length 3. Or as an object it would be `{ length: 3 }`. With, e.g. `Array(Array(3))` you would create an array with `undefined`s `{ 0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, length: 3 }`. And `.map` only iterates over existing keys.